# Is S3NativeFileSystem call killing my Pyspark Application on AWS EMR 4.6.0

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, emr

My Spark application is failing when it has to access numerous CSV files (~1000 @ 63MB each) from S3, and pipe them into a Spark RDD. The actual process of splitting up the CSV seems to work, but an extra function call to S3NativeFileSystem seems to be causing an error and the job to crash.

To begin, the following is my PySpark Application:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext("local", "Simple App")
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
import time

startTime = float(time.time())

dataPath = 's3://PATHTODIRECTORY/'
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", "MYKEY")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", "MYSECRETKEY")

def buildSchemaDF(tableName, columnList):
    currentRDD = sc.textFile(dataPath + tableName).map(lambda line: line.split("|"))
    currentDF = currentRDD.toDF(columnList)
    return currentDF

loadStartTime = float(time.time())
lineitemDF = buildSchemaDF('lineitem*', ['l_orderkey','l_partkey','l_suppkey','l_linenumber','l_quantity','l_extendedprice','l_discount','l_tax','l_returnflag','l_linestatus','l_shipdate','l_commitdate','l_receiptdate','l_shipinstruct','l_shipmode','l_comment'])
lineitemDF.registerTempTable("lineitem")
loadTimeElapsed = float(time.time()) - loadStartTime

queryStartTime = float(time.time())

qstr = """
    SELECT
        lineitem.l_returnflag,
        lineitem.l_linestatus,
        sum(l_quantity) as sum_qty,
        sum(l_extendedprice) as sum_base_price,
        sum(l_discount) as sum_disc,
        sum(l_tax) as sum_tax,
        avg(l_quantity) as avg_qty,
        avg(l_extendedprice) as avg_price,
        avg(l_discount) as avg_disc,
        count(l_orderkey) as count_order
    FROM
        lineitem
    WHERE
        l_shipdate <= '19981001'
    GROUP BY
        l_returnflag,
        l_linestatus
    ORDER BY
        l_returnflag,
        l_linestatus
    """
tpch1DF = sqlContext.sql(qstr)

queryTimeElapsed = float(time.time()) - queryStartTime
totalTimeElapsed = float(time.time()) - startTime

tpch1DF.show()

queryResults = [qstr, loadTimeElapsed, queryTimeElapsed, totalTimeElapsed]
distData = sc.parallelize(queryResults)
distData.saveAsTextFile(dataPath + 'queryResults.csv')

print 'Load Time: ' + str(loadTimeElapsed)
print 'Query Time: ' + str(queryTimeElapsed)
print 'Total Time: ' + str(totalTimeElapsed)
```

To take it step by step I start off by spinning up a Spark EMR Cluster with the following AWS CLI command (carriage returns added for readability):

```
aws emr create-cluster --name "Big TPCH Spark cluster2" --release-label emr-4.6.0 
--applications Name=Spark --ec2-attributes KeyName=blazing-test-aws 
--log-uri s3://aws-logs-132950491118-us-west-2/elasticmapreduce/j-1WZ39GFS3IX49/ 
--instance-type m3.2xlarge --instance-count 6 --use-default-roles
```

After the EMR cluster finishes provisioning I then copy over my Pyspark application onto the master node at '/home/hadoop/pysparkApp.py'. With it copied over I'm able to add the Step for spark-submit.

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-1DQJ8BDL1394N --steps
Type=spark,Name=SparkTPCHTests,Args=[--deploy-mode,cluster,-
conf,spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=true,--num-executors,5,--executor
cores,5,--executor memory,20g,/home/hadoop/tpchSpark.py]
,ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE
```

Now if I run this step over only a few of the aforementioned CSV files the final results will be generated, but the script will still claim to have failed.

I think it's associated with an extra call to S3NativeFileSystem, but I'm not certain. These are the Yarn log messages I'm getting which lead me to that conclusion. The first call appears to work just fine:

```
16/05/15 23:18:00 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: s3://data-set-builder/splitLineItem2/lineitemad:0+64901757
16/05/15 23:18:00 INFO latency: StatusCode=[200], ServiceName=[Amazon S3], AWSRequestID=[ED8011CE4E1F6F18], ServiceEndpoint=[https://data-set-builder.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com], HttpClientPoolLeasedCount=0, RetryCapacityConsumed=0, RequestCount=1, HttpClientPoolPendingCount=0, HttpClientPoolAvailableCount=2, ClientExecuteTime=[77.956], HttpRequestTime=[77.183], HttpClientReceiveResponseTime=[20.028], RequestSigningTime=[0.229], CredentialsRequestTime=[0.003], ResponseProcessingTime=[0.128], HttpClientSendRequestTime=[0.35],
```

While the second one does not seem to execute properly, resulting in "Partial Results" (206 Error):

```
16/05/15 23:18:00 INFO S3NativeFileSystem: Opening 's3://data-set-builder/splitLineItem2/lineitemad' for reading
16/05/15 23:18:00 INFO latency: StatusCode=[206], ServiceName=[Amazon S3], AWSRequestID=[10BDDE61AE13AFBE], ServiceEndpoint=[https://data-set-builder.s3.amazonaws.com], HttpClientPoolLeasedCount=0, RetryCapacityConsumed=0, RequestCount=1, HttpClientPoolPendingCount=0, HttpClientPoolAvailableCount=2, Client Execute Time=[296.86], HttpRequestTime=[295.801], HttpClientReceiveResponseTime=[293.667], RequestSigningTime=[0.204], CredentialsRequestTime=[0.002], ResponseProcessingTime=[0.34], HttpClientSendRequestTime=[0.337],
16/05/15 23:18:02 INFO ApplicationMaster: Waiting for spark context initialization ...
```

I'm lost as to why it's even making the second call to S3NativeFileSystem when the first one appears to have responded effectively and even split the file. Is this something that is a product of my EMR configuration? I know S3Native has file limit issues and that a straight S3 call is optimal, which is what I've tried to do, but this call seems to be there no matter what I do. Please help!

Also, to add a few other error messages in my Yarn Log in case they are relevant.

1)

```
16/05/15 23:19:22 ERROR ApplicationMaster: SparkContext did not initialize after waiting for 100000 ms. Please check earlier log output for errors. Failing the application.
16/05/15 23:19:22 INFO ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 13, (reason: Timed out waiting for SparkContext.)
```

2)

```
16/05/15 23:19:22 ERROR DiskBlockObjectWriter: Uncaught exception while reverting partial writes to file /mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1463354019776_0001/blockmgr-f847744b-c87a-442c-9135-57cae3d1f6f0/2b/temp_shuffle_3fe2e09e-f8e4-4e5d-ac96-1538bdc3b401
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1463354019776_0001/blockmgr-f847744b-c87a-442c-9135-57cae3d1f6f0/2b/temp_shuffle_3fe2e09e-f8e4-4e5d-ac96-1538bdc3b401 (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.revertPartialWritesAndClose(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:162)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.stop(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:226)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/05/15 23:19:22 ERROR BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter: Error while deleting file /mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1463354019776_0001/blockmgr-f847744b-c87a-442c-9135-57cae3d1f6f0/2b/temp_shuffle_3fe2e09e-f8e4-4e5d-ac96-1538bdc3b401
16/05/15 23:19:22 WARN TaskMemoryManager: leak 32.3 MB memory from org.apache.spark.unsafe.map.BytesToBytesMap@762be8fe
16/05/15 23:19:22 ERROR Executor: Managed memory leak detected; size = 33816576 bytes, TID = 14
16/05/15 23:19:22 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 13.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 14)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1463354019776_0001/blockmgr-f847744b-c87a-442c-9135-57cae3d1f6f0/3a/temp_shuffle_b9001fca-bba9-400d-9bc4-c23c002e0aa9 (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.open(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:140)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 3):

Order of precedence for spark configurations is :

SparkContext (code/application) > Spark-submit > Spark-defaults.conf

So couple of things to point here -

1. Use YARN cluster as deploy mode and master in your spark submit command -

   `spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn ...`

   OR

   `spark-submit --master yarn-cluster ...`
2. Remove "local" string from line `sc = SparkContext("local", "Simple App")` in your code. Use `conf = SparkConf().setAppName(appName)
   sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)` to initialize Spark context.

Ref - http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html